# Scope of event handler after object instantiation again

Tags: vb.net

I have a global variable:

```
Public myPerson As New Person
```

Then I attach an event handler:

```
AddHandler myPerson.OnClose, AddressOf DoWhatever
```

Then somewhere else in the program I recreate my object:

```
myPerson = New Person
```

Will my event handler still be attached to new myPerson, or do I need to add it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does my event handler will be still attached to new myPerson or do i need to add it again?

Event handlers are specific to each instance of the class. When you do `myPerson = New Person` you instantiate a completely new instance of the `Person` class that has its own references, variables, and events.

Remember that just because you refer to the same variable it doesn't mean its the same class instance. A class instance can be referenced by multiple variables. For example, here:

```
Dim Person1 As New Person
Dim Person2 As Person = Person1
Dim Person3 As Person = Person1

AddHandler Person1.OnClose, AddressOf DoWhatever
```

all three variables refer to the very same instance of the `Person` class. So if you'd call something on `Person3` that raises the `OnClose` event, the event handler would still get called.

> If answer is -no it will be disposed

The handler will only be disposed/detached if you detach it manually or if the Garbage Collector disposes/collects your first instance. In my above example, reinstantiating/changing `Person1` will not remove the event handler since `Person2` and `Person3` still reference the class instance.

This fiddle illustrates what I'm talking about: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8XiH19

As you see the only person reported closed is John, referenced by `Person2`, while calling `myPerson.Close()` on the newly instantiated person yielded nothing.

> what if i would add the same handler again, would it be then called twice as i would have two same handlers attached twice?

No. As said above the event handler is specific to *the class instance*, not the variable.

Comment: you said `class` multiple time where `instance` would be more suitable. This can be misleading

Comment: @Sehnsucht : Is this better? I changed to the words "class instance" instead of just "instance" because I felt that was even more clear. Thanks for your feedback, by the way. :)

Comment: seems ok to me :)

Comment: @Visual Vincent So simply saying 1st case) having myPerson = New Person - if i add handler to it and after that i do myPerson = New Person - then handler will be detached and if i would like to have it again i have to addhandler again to it 2nd case) having myPerson = New Person - if i add handler let's say 6 times - then if event raised it will be called 6 times (not one) 3rd case) Having myPerson = New Person which i add some handler and then my2ndPerson = myperson - then if i do again myPerson = New Person - then myPerson will lose his handler but not my2ndPerson . Is it all correct?

Comment: also to the 3rd case) my2ndPerson will keep all variables which it inherited from myPerson

Comment: @JimmyJimm : **1)** The handler will not be detached unless the class is disposed/garbage collected. However _each instance_ (every time you call `myPerson = New Person`) will have its own handlers (again, this is illustrated by my fiddle). You would have to use `AddHandler` again because you have never subscribed to the event _**of the new instance**_.

Comment: @JimmyJimm : **2)** If you add a handler _**to the same instance**_ 6 times then the handler will be called 6 times, yes. -- **3.1)** The `myPerson` variable points to a new class instance, so it will no longer have any handlers (this is also illustrated by my fiddle). -- **3.2)** And yes, `my2ndPerson` will maintain all data from the old `myPerson`. You can read more about how reference types (classes) work on [**the MSDN documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

Comment: @JimmyJimm : I'm not the best at describing stuff in drawn images, but I made a few that hopefully will help you get a better grip on how reference types work: [**\[ 1 \]**](http://www.mydoomsite.com/Bilder/ReferenceTypesExample1.png) -- [**\[ 2 \]**](http://www.mydoomsite.com/Bilder/ReferenceTypesExample2.png) -- [**\[ 3 \]**](http://www.mydoomsite.com/Bilder/ReferenceTypesExample3.png) -- [**\[ 4 \]**](http://www.mydoomsite.com/Bilder/ReferenceTypesExample4.png) -- [**\[ 5 \]**](http://www.mydoomsite.com/Bilder/ReferenceTypesExample5.png)

Comment: @JimmyJimm : As you can see in the third image event handlers are attached to the class instance, not the variable.